# c++ VS 2010 to VS 2019 upgrade. After upgrade need const after argument list. why?

Tags: c++

Very long term C++ programmer. I just now upgraded from Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio 2019. After the upgrade, a program that compiled fine with VS 2010 failed to compile with VS 2019 with error C3848. The failure occurred using std::set which when used with a class needs a comparison function, implemented with operator(). A C3848 error says that the signature of my class object doesn't match the signature in std::set and the mismatch is that one signature has a const and the other does not.

I already have a perfectly good fix which is to add const after the argument list for my comparison function. I should probably just declare victory and move on because I have a solution, but the solution makes no sense to me. All documentation on this situation says that the const after the argument list applies to the "this" variable and for example, it allows two member method definitions, one for when the "this" variable is a constant and when for when the "this" variable is not a constant. The reason this explanation makes no sense to me is that my little comparison function has no "this" variable - or at least none that I know of.

The basic structure of my comparison function is

```
class Mycomp
{
  public:
      bool operator() (const Myclass& x, const Myclass& y){... }
};
```

which returns true if x precedes y in order and which returns false otherwise. Mycomp makes no reference to any sort of "this" variable and only makes reference to the arguments x and y. Such functions are extraordinarily common when using things like std::set, std::vector, std::sort, and numerous other services in the C++ standard library and I have writing code like this for close to 30 years. It's the first time I have ever run into this problem.

To complete the story, the std:set is defined as

```
    std::set<Myclass,Mycomp> the_set; // the name of the set can be
                                      // anything, so I made be it
                                      // be "the_set"
```

This far through the process, there is no compile error. The compile error occurs when I try to insert something into the set.

```
    Myclass an_object;    // instantiate a member of the class
    // code goes here to put some data into the_object
    the_set.insert(an_object); // insert the object into the set
```

In this case, "insert" is a member method of the std::set class, and my comparison function was associated the set I called "the_set" at the time "the_set" was instantiated. The compile error occurs on in the insert, not on the definition of the comparison function nor when the std::set is instantiated. In any case, the fix is to add const to the comparisonfunction, viz.,

```
    class Mycomp
{
  public:
      bool operator() (const Myclass& x, const Myclass& y) const {... }
    };
```

I guess it makes me wonder the following. Typically you have non-static member methods which do have a "this" variable and you have static member methods which do not have a "this" variable. So what are operator() and operator<() etc., static or non-static? I have never had an operator type member method that had a "this" variable, but I have also never declared an operator type member method to be static. So what is going on? Why do you have to declare the "this" variable to be constant when there is no "this" variable?

Comment: Because that the requirement of a comparison object.

Comment: I remember VS 2008 having an issue in release builds (not debug builds, strangely), if the `const` were left out.

Answer (score 2):

> I have never had an operator type member method that had a "this" variable, but I have also never declared an operator type member method to be static.

You say this as though there are more than two choices. If a function is a member of a type, then it is either static or non-static. If you did not write `static` in the member declaration/definition, then it *has a `this` pointer*. It's there whether you use it or not.

Your `operator()` overload is called on a live instance of `Mycomp`. Therefore, it takes one as a pointer. And therefore, the relationship between that function's execution and that object is important. Previously, `set` didn't care if the function modified the instance. However, it was undefined behavior to do so, because `set` was allowed to create and destroy such instances as it saw fit.

Rather than leave such modifications as undetectable UB, the C++ committee decided to simply forbid the comparison operator from modifying the object.